# cell content with regex in csv file using python

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a csv file like=>

```
apple, 23, 45 
abricot, 45 12
grape,  123 985
apple, 18, 450
```

I would like to get row thanks to identifier, for instance get from apple row.. 
here's my code:

```
import csv
import re
exampleFile=open('test-csvred.csv')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
for row in exampleReader:
    a=str(row)
    print ('Row #' + str(exampleReader.line_num)+' ' +a)
    t=re.match("apple(.*)",a).group(1)
```

the code gives me=> NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
I don't really know what is my mistake... 
thanks in advance

Comment: why  are you using the csv lib if you want a string? Post what the actual content looks like and what you expect as output

Comment: `re.match` only searches for a match at the beginning of the string. Try `re.search`.

Comment: re.search gives me the same error message.

Comment: I use csv because I need those docs to edit contents.
I would like to extract the int of the third cell each time line begins by apple

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically doing what `str.startswith` can do:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("apple"):
            print(line)
```

Your code is obviously going to fail unless every single line startswith `"apple"` as `match` or `search` will return `None` when there is no match.  Your `csv` file also seems to be a mess, there are different amounts of whitespace and missing commas so it is not suitable to be parsed by the `csv` lib.

If you want the line numbers too, use `enumerate`:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for ind, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if line.startswith("apple"):
            print(line)
```

Comment: @user2216280, no worries, this  basically does what your own code wa attempting to do. The csv lib is not really suitable for the sample input you provided if you need to split the data you can str.split and str.rstrip

Comment: for ind, line in enumerate(f, 1):
doesn't seem to gives the line number where the startswith function is true...

Comment: Yes, just add  `ind` to the print,  `print(ind, line)`